# Search string in cdata block

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, cdata

One of the columns of my Microsoft SQL Server table contains a string formatted as XML

```
<root>
    <de><![CDATA[something]]></de>
    <fr><![CDATA[something]]></fr>
    <it><![CDATA[something]]></it>
    <en><![CDATA[something]]></en>
</root>
```

or

```
<root>
    <de>something</de>
    <it>something</it>
    <fr>something</fr>
    <en>something</en>
</root>
```

I need to extract all the records that contains a certain word, no matter if there's the CDATA or not.

So I structured the where conditions in LINQ in this way:

```
vc.Url.Contains(">" + URL + "<") || vc.Url.Contains("cdata[[]" + URL + "]")
```

If the searchtext matches and there is not CDATA, then the where condition works and I get the result.

if the searchtext matches and there is the CDATA, then the where condition doesn't work.

If I execute the query via SQL Server Management Studio:

```
  where vc.Url like '%>something<%' OR vc.Url like '%cdata[[]something]%'
```

I obtain the expected result.

Any idea about how to write the where condition in the right way and obtain the same result via SQL and via LINQ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework automatically escapes any special characters passed in to `Contains`, `StartsWith`, and `EndsWith`, so you don't need to use `[[]`. Try:

```
vc.Url.Contains(">" + URL + "<") || vc.Url.Contains("cdata[" + URL + "]")
```

Comment: Forgot to specify that I use LLBLGenPro as ORM and not EF. I suppose that has to work too..in few minutes i can check!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It returns me no record if the URL is in a CDATA field. It works well if the URL is not in a CDATA field.

Comment: @matan: Does LLBLGenPro have an option to trace the generated queries?

Comment: After having analyzed the sql statements, I noticed that there was a DLL misalignement. DLLs of the Class Library project where I had the problem, are referenced on a website project. Fact is that I was working on the new version of the Class Library project, while website still had the references to the old version.